# Multiple Query Results in Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, datatables, multiple-records

I've been developing a database for a call billing system in Access 2013. I've encountered a very strange issue when creating a query in Microsoft Access 2013. On the Query design tab.

If I create a new Query and have that Query display just one field of a table with 38 entries, the output shows 38 records, which is correct.

However, when I 'add' another table from show table command. Depending on the number of records in the new table, e.g 3 and then run the query without adding any additional fields to the query, the output shows a total of 114 records i.e 38 sets of 3 duplicates!

I've no idea as to why it does this?

Comment: You need to join the 2 tables using a common data field.  Otherwise, Access generates the result of every record from table1 matched with every record from table2.

Comment: I've just added a link between the tables in the Query Design View, and it works! 

I added these same links in the table relationships manager window, and thought that was the only place where they needed to be linked-obviously not.

I had no idea that these where two separate types of links?

Thank you very much for your input, it's been very helpful! :)